# Serialize all form data including empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

I have dynamic form that have different kind of input fields. Can have text, paragraf text option and check boxes. I could use serialize function

```
jQuery('#frm_submit').submit(function(){
var postData = jQuery(this).serialize();
doFunction(postData);
});
```

but anu option or check box that are left empty are not serialized. It is required to do all validation on serverside and i need all data sent. How to do this?

Comment: If you don't receive any data for a given form element on the serverside, assume it's empty.

Comment: Also implement some client side validation so you try to make sure that user fills all required fields

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, but i dont know names of form fields until submit, I made working server side validation for empty field, but that only wotks for text bozes, not check and option.

Comment: @adeneo All must be on server side..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        jQuery('#frm_submit').find('[name]').not('[type="file"]').each(function () {
            var s = '';
            if ('' !== s) {
                s += '&';
            }
            var name = encodeURIComponent(jQuery(this).attr('name'));
            var value = jQuery(this).val();
            if ('SELECT' === jQuery(this).prop('tagName') && true === jQuery(this).prop('multiple')) {
                // handling select multiple here
                if (null !== value && value.length) {
                    var x = '';
                    for (var i in value) {
                        if ('' !== x) {
                            x += '&';
                        }
                        x += name + '=' + value[i];
                    }
                    s += x;
                }
                else {
                    s += name + '='; // null
                }
            }
            else {
                s += name + '=' + value;
            }
            doFunction(s);            
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: here is example html: